# Creating Custom Dashboard in Flurry Analytics

Tags: android, ios, dashboard, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have my app registered on Flurry Analytics. 
App has multiple events with parameters. 
I am able to see the custom results while using the query tool.

My question is, Is it possible to create a custom dashboard using my custom queries so that I can see all of my data when I come to this dashboard rather than hitting a saved query every time.

Comment: Can you reach out to us directly at support@flurry.com?

Comment: I did not get a response from the support team hence I have posted over here. Finally, I got the reply stating that they are currently not supporting this feature in the new Flurry for now.